# Cannot install the driver of BeagleBone on the Windows 10

Tags: debian, windows-10, driver, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

When I try to install the drivers of my BeagleBone on the Windows 10, I get :
[image]

Knowing that I have the latest Image of Beaglebone which : 
[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A current / latest image does not need *any* additional drivers installed.

You should have:

- One USB drive with files
- One USB serial port
- One USB network port

The device exposes a second network port that is not used by Windows. Other operating systems prefer that port over the one used by Windows.

*Note:* If you don't see those devices, then your Beaglebone has not booted into the image. Usually that's pretty obvious by looking at the LEDs. There should be one solid, and two blinking. If you have problems, write the image to the card again and also make sure to hold down S2 while powering on the device!

Comment: Thank you @TBR, so I don't need to unsigned the drivers of windows?

Comment: Correct. Windows should by itself figure out the right Microsoft generic drivers for those three devices. No third party drivers required.

Comment: Thank you @TBR, how to eliminate protected write permission on the beaglebone please ? I want to edit the file START.htm for running my application

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 rejects the BeagleBoard drivers because they are not signed.  You can temporarily disable required driver signing by going through the Advanced Boot options.

> You can use the advanced boot options menu to boot Windows 10 with driver signature enforcement
>   disabled. This isn’t a permanent configuration change. The next time
>   you restart Windows, it will boot with driver signature enforcement
>   enabled—unless you go through this menu again.
>
> To do this, get to the Windows 8 or 10 advanced boot options menu. For
>   example, you can hold down the Shift key while you click the “Restart”
>   option in Windows. Your computer will restart into the menu.

See here for detailed step-by-step instructions with screen grabs (Option Two):
https://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when installing drivers for my BeagleBone Black board.
You need to **disable driver signature enforcement** before installing drivers if you are using Windows 10.

Go to **Setting > Updates & Security > Recovery > Advanced startup >** click on **Restart**

After restarting, Windows switch to **Advanced startup** mode.
Go to Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Startup settings > click on **Restart**

After restarting, press **F7** to select **Disable driver signature enforcement**

[image]

Now you can install drivers for your board.

I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/mxMMf-8d6x4